# carrierwave: point to existing image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

In my rails app, I'm using Carrierwave to upload images on Amazon S3.  I'd like to point to existing Amazon S3 images without having to re-upload the image.  For example, if I have an existing Amazon S3 image at **http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/image/path/0001/image.jpg**, can I update an image's path to point to this image?  I don't want to use the remote upload option because I really just want to use the same exact image that's already there (but save it in my record's "path" attribute).

In the console, I've tried:

```
image.update_attributes(:path=> "http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/image/path/0001/image.jpg")
```

but this fails to override the image's path.

Comment: How were you able to resolve this?

Comment: I ended up not creating a new record and just pointing to the original record.

Comment: hi @scientiffic have you found a solution for that ? i'm very interesting

Answer (score 5):

Chiming in, better late than never!  Caveat:  This is for rails 4, and I am testing on rails 4.1 only at the moment.

This is harder than it should be, methinks!  The reason this was absolutely crucial to me was that I am attaching 100MB+ MP3 files, which I cannot receive on my host, due to CloudFlare SSL limitations (and common sense).  Fortunately, AWS supports preauthorized uploads, and I got carrierwave to do the right thing for me:

Step 1: get carrierwave to tell me where it would store a file if it could:

```
 m.raw_write_attribute('file','file.mp3');
 url = m.file.url
 signed = aws_presigned_url(url)
```

`raw_write_attribute` does not save anything, it just bypasses carrierwave when setting the value.  This makes the object act as if it read 'file.mp3' out of the database.  Then you can ask Carrierwave "where the file lives".  I then upload the file directly from the client to S3.  When that's done, I make another API call to Rails, which performs the following code:

```
 m.raw_write_attribute('file','file.mp3');
 m.update_attribute('file','file.mp3');
```

These two paired get around Carrierwave.  The first makes carrierwave think that the 'file' column is set to 'file.mp3', the second explicitly tells rails to persist 'file.mp3' to the DB.  Because of the `raw_write_attribute` call, Carrierwave allows the second through un-changed.

Answer (score 3):

In my case `update_column` and `update_columns` worked great:

```
model.update_columns file_1: 'filename.txt'
```

Update column is with comma:

```
model.update_column :file_1, 'filename.txt'
```

This will not run any callback and set column to `filename.txt`.

When I do `model.file_1.url` I get the right S3 URL.

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late to the party, but you can use Active Record's raw_write_attribute method something like:

@image.raw_write_attribute(:path, "http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/image/path/0001/image.jpg")

Comment: As far as I can tell, this does not save the value to the DB, and doesn't even allow you to write it to the DB with @image.save, because as far as the model is concerned, there is nothing to save!

Answer (score 1):

I found that you can actually do this, for example if your `mount_uploader` is `:path`, then:

```
image.remote_path_url = "http://test.s3.amazonaws.com/image/path/0001/image.jpg"
image.save
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.  As I mentioned in my original post, I didn't want to re-upload the file, which I believe is what you're doing with remote_path_url and save.

Comment: Any reason you don't want to re-upload the file? In my case, it will replace the existing file and it's still faster rather than upload from local machine. Unfortunately I don't see there's any alternative ways for carrierwave without doing this.

Comment: I found that re-uploading the file was too slow for my application.  Instead, I just detect whether or not the new record points to another image and replace the image in the view (rather than in my database).